# How to upload input to a text file in php

Tags: php, html, forms, upload, submit

I want to upload the contents written in the text box in a text file using php. But also they should only be written if the string contains a particular pattern.

here's my php code

```
<?php

$data = $_POST["text"];
public function copy(){
    if (strpos($data, '123') !== false){
    $myfile = "uploads/mydata.txt";
    $fh = fopen($myfile, 'w') or die("can't open file");
    fwrite($fh, $data);
    fclose($fh);
    }
}
?>
```

It says unexpected public on line 4.
and my form is:

```
    <?php require_once('tally.php') ?>
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <title>
    </title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <form action="index.php" method="post">
        Input the first record
        <input type="text" name="text">
        <input type="submit" name="submit" action="submit">
        Submit
        </submit>
    </form>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Thanks for helping

Answer (score 1, accepted):

why are you using fopen, just use file_put_contents.

The input name is text and in php you are trying to receive $_POST['data'].
Change name of input to data or change the php code and get $_POST['text'].

also your submit button is not xhtml or html5 standard compliant. change it to  no need for closing tag or additional text.

I cannot see where are you calling the copy function.

code should be something like this.

```
<?php

$data = $_POST["data"];
if(!empty($data)) {
    copy2($data);
}
function copy2($data){
    if (strpos($data, '123') !== false){
    $myfile = "uploads/mydata.txt";
    $fh = fopen($myfile, 'w') or die("can't open file");
    fwrite($fh, $data);
    fclose($fh);
    }
}
?>
```

HTML goes like this:

```
<?php require_once('tally.php') ?>
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <title>
    </title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <form action="index.php" method="post">
        Input the first record
        <input type="text" name="text">
        <input type="submit" value="submit">
    </form>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Oh! what was i doing now I used the file_put_contents and changed it to $_POST['text'] but it still gives the same error @KoKo    here's new code:       <?php

 $data = $_POST["text"];
    function copy()
 {
  if (strpos($data, '123') !== false)
  {
  file_put_contents("mydata.txt",$data);
     }
 }
?>     Still gives the same error

Comment: can you show the error? and why do you check for strpos($data, '123')?

Comment: well I think php uses predefined copy function so i changed it to copy2. The error got removed but it still doesn't write to the file @KoKo. N yeah i need to check for that string occurence so that it only uploads if the input contains '123'

Comment: Thanks man! It worked. The problem was i never called the function. Anyways thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the word public if this function is not in a class.

```
public function copy(){
```

becomes

```
function copy(){
```

Comment: I tried that before @Christian it says cannot redeclare copy() on line 11

Comment: Then you have another function with same name somewhere else. Rename the function to copy_b and see if that works

Answer (score -1):

There is not tag associated with data. Please add:

```
 <input type="text" name="data">
```

Comment: Hi there. A number of your answers have the introductory paragraph formatted as code, and this is creating editing work. Please apply code block formatting only to content that needs it - thanks.